# Is time-stamp broken?

Tags: timestamped

I use GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.23) of 2020-11-09 (bundled with Ubuntu 21.10) with this init file:

```
% cat ~/.emacs.d/init-1.el
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
```

I have this file:

```
% cat good
modification : (2022-01-21 17:08:15 WET)
<!-- Local Variables: -->
<!-- time-stamp-pattern: "-10/modification :[ \t]+\\\\?[\"(]+%:y-%02m-%02d %02H:%02M:%02S %Z\\\\?[\")]" -->
<!-- End: -->
```

(ended by an empty line, not visible here).

If you wish to reproduce my experiment, you may save time by creating `~/.emacs.d/init-1.el` and `good` in your system and protecting `good`.

Then run this in Terminal:

```
cp good good1
chmod u+w good1
emacs -Q --load ~/.emacs.d/init-1.el good1&
```

In Emacs, delete or remove the trailing new line or run `M-x time-stamp`, check that the timestamp updates.  So far so good.

Capitalize the `m` in both instances of `modification` in the file `good1`.

`time-stamp` is now broken: editing and saving or `M-x time-stamp` won't ever update the timestamp again, unless you restore the initial `m`s or kill the buffer and reload the file.

Can you confirm my experiment?

Is it Emacs bug?

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are only read when the file is opened or when the major mode of the buffer is set. See the "Local Variables in Files" section of the Emacs manual: `(info "(emacs) File Variables")`.

If you change it in the buffer and save, that does not change the value of the `time-stamp-pattern` variable. You need to kill the buffer and do `find-file` again; or revert the buffer from the file with `M-x revert-buffer`; or simpler, call `normal-mode`.

Thanks to @db48x and @phils for correcting and enhancing the answer.

Comment: Simpler to just call `normal-mode`.

Comment: Since (IIRC) Emacs 26, local variables are processed when changing the major mode of an existing buffer, rather than only when initially visiting the file.

Comment: You are right: I'll expand the answer to include that.